# How to know if some data type is from std?

Tags: python, c++, types, namespaces, std

Is there any list of types inside std namespace? I'm writing translator from uml diagram to c++ code, that should add std:: when it's needed. How my program should know that string has prefix std:: and int doesn't.

Comment: Why would you need to add this in the parser? If the program leaves out the namespace prefix, it has to use `using namespace std`, and the names will be found in the namespace.

Comment: What are you going to do about a program with a user defined type `vector` that also uses `std::vector` ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header lists all the standard headers. You'd have to go through all of them to get all the names that they define.

Comment: but adding `using namespace std` isn't a good practice

Comment: Strictly speaking, this wouldn't be the job of the parser. The parser takes what is *there* and builds a syntax tree. Determine if and where a `std::` prefix is missing would be the job of something performing semantic analysis.

Comment: If you don't use that, then you can't refer to those names without the `std::` prefix. Why do you want to add it in your parser?

Comment: @lorakis well neither is referring to `std::string` in any other manner than `std::string`, because it gets confusing. There's projects that essentially rebuild their own STL and "string" doesn't mean anything by itself, which is why we can only know either from context, or namespace, which is why most STL types are written out as is with `std::` instead of renaming anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any list of types inside std namespace?

All of them are mentioned in the standard, as well as any documentation that covers the standard. There's no plain list that I know of however.

> How my program should know that string has prefix std:: and int doesn't.

Your program should know that `int` isn't in a namespace because it is a keyword. You can find a list of all keywords in the [tab:lex.key] table in the standard.

However, just because an identifier is `string`, doesn't mean that it is in the `std` namespace. Example:

```
namespace not_std {
struct string {};
string s; // this isn't std::string
}

#include <string>
using std::string;
string s; // this is std::string
```

Adding the `std::` qualifier would be correct only in the latter case.

---

> I'm writing translator from uml diagram to c++ code

In my opinion, your translator should translate `string` into `string` and `std::string` into `std::string`. Let the author of the diagram ensure that their names are correctly qualified. If the translator has to make guesses, then there will be cases where it guesses incorrectly.

Comment: [tab:lex.key] is exactly what I needed, thank you!